# Load multiple versions of a package in npm

Tags: javascript, web, service, npm, versions

I am setting up a web API and I'd like to offer multiple versions of the underlying library.

In short, I'd like to call it with:
http://myapi/x.y.z/method
where x.y.z is the version of the underlying library I'm using.

I'm using npm to handle my libraries and seem to be able to specify only one version of the dependencies.

I thought about manually downloading each versions in sub folders of my service but I'm not a big fan of it.
Instead, I'd like to just have a list of allowed versions in my config and that it loads them at service start-up for future use.

What's the best way to achieve multi-versions API on a JavaScript web service?
I'm open to other package managers as well (instead of npm).

Comment: Yes, I'd like to see an answer to this question as well. This could be very useful if for example you are switching git branches and `node_modules` is gitignored.

Answer (score 0):

i hope to help, if you want to use different versions, eg express:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "express": "~3.x",
}
```

So you will tell no matter npm express version you use, always be from the version "3"

Comment: Yes but only a single version of express 3.x will be loaded. I want to load different versions and within my code to choose this or that version depending on the one the client requested (and not a library like express which drives everything but a small helper library)

Comment: I understand, you are who choose the version, because you are going to work with the version(s), not customer. Who dependencies of npm plan to use